# Access Controls (Text Boxes and Combo Boxes) added in Runtime to Windows Foam

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls, tablelayoutpanel

I am adding User Control to my Main Windows Foam, the User Control consist of Tablelayoutpanel which include 2 Combo Boxes,1 Button and 4 Text Boxes, as shown in the picture below:[image]

How can I access each of these controls as I add more Controls in Runtime Such as this in image below[image]

In my practice I know to access controls which are created in Design Time but I don't know how to access Control which are generated in Runtime.

I tried Button Click event, but It shows Click event of Single button only, how can I access Click Event for multiple button added in Runtime.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but your answers shows only two button events, I have to add multiple buttons and combo boxes how can I differentiate between them in runtime? & why you need to define UserControl1 userControl = new UserControl1();, if it is already created in design time?

Comment: Is my update solve your problem? At the beginning of usercontrol design, you should set easy-to-identify names for buttons and combo. In the last code, I mistakenly wrote name as text, which may affect your interpretation. You can easily use foreach (Control ctrl in this.XXX.Controls) to find specific controls.

Comment: I did not fully understand the concept as described in answer, I have to delete each User Control when cross button is clicked, How should I know which cross button is clicked?, this is the fact confusing me a lot.

Comment: I have First User Control named as "EffectGroupUserControl" which contain "Time Label" & "Add Button", each "EffectGroupUserControl" consist of one or more "SingleEffectUserControl"s which consist of two "Combo Boxes", One "Remove Button" and Four "Text Boxes". and now the problem is How I can access each of them as seperate controls?

Comment: You can't directly access them as individual controls, they all belong to their own EffectGroupUserControl. You can only access its sub-controls through EffectGroupUserControl. Otherwise, why not use them directly, but make them as EffectGroupUserControl? No matter how many "SingleEffectUserControl" you create, they also have their own Name property. You can still access them, and the child controls that belong to them, through these properties.

Comment: "I have to delete each User Control when cross button is clicked, How should I know which cross button is clicked?" I can't understand what you are trying to do. And for me, for this Usercontrol, the purpose of our creation is to reduce the workload. The events of the sub-controls should be fixed. So you can create their events directly when making Usercontrol, which will make the work easier.

Comment: I am trying to delete the "SingleEffectUserControl" from the "EffectGroupUserControl"'s TableLayoutPanel when the cross button of "SingleEffectUserControl" is clicked, that's why I want to know exactly which "SingleEffectUserControl"'s Cross Button is Clicked.

Comment: Please check my update2.

Comment: Thank you. from Update2 I got the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update2:

Do you mean remove the control's parent control?

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 userControl11 = new UserControl1();
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(userControl11);
    foreach (Control item in userControl11.Controls)
    {
        if (item.Name == "button1")
        {
            item.Click += (sender1, e1) =>
            {
                Control childControl = sender1 as Control;
                if (childControl != null && childControl.Parent != null)
                {
                    Control parentControl = childControl.Parent;
                    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(parentControl);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

Update:

I misunderstood your runtime creation.

In fact, even multiple usercontrols are created at design time. They all have their own names.

You can add events to them using the same method.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.userControl12.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.Name is "button1")
        {
            Button btn = (Button)ctrl;
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
        }
        else if (ctrl.Name is "button2")
        {
            Button btn = (Button)ctrl;
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(Button2_Click);
        }
    }
}
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
}
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("World");
}
```

[image]

---

This example shows how to add your own events to multiple buttons contained in a usercontrol.

Create a usercontrol as follows:

[image]

Create a winform project as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WindowsFormsControlLibrary1;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl1 userControl = new UserControl1();
            foreach (Control ctrl in userControl.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl.Text is "button1")
                {
                    Button btn = (Button)ctrl;
                    btn.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
                }
                else if (ctrl.Text is "button2")
                {
                    Button btn = (Button)ctrl;
                    btn.Click += new EventHandler(Button2_Click);
                }

            }
            userControl.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            // userControl.Size = new Size(200, 100);
            panel1.Controls.Add(userControl);

        }
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("World");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

Using this as an example, you can add individual events to them, or you can add a unified event.

Just find them from the corresponding container.